# Can moderators see my password?

Tags: support, accounts, moderator-abilities

I signed up but I'm afraid because all my passwords are the same.

Can moderators see our passwords in Stack Overflow?

Please don't hack me.

Comment: "all passwords are same" - you really shouldn't do this. See [Why You Should Use a Password Manager and How to Get Started](http://www.howtogeek.com/141500/why-you-should-use-a-password-manager-and-how-to-get-started/)

Comment: Having said that you shouldn't worry too much, just be carefull. Being carefull means, amongst other things, not telling all this information. What if someone (unlikly) have noticed your password? Now he knows all places he can use it, otherwise he still needed to guess where and wich username. But again, don't worry too much.

Comment: Why would you worry about SO but not any of the other sites you gave your password to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We don't hold passwords on Stack Overflow. At all.

That's why we use OpenId - so password management is done on the end of the openId provider (say Google, Facebook or whatever other OpenId provider you use).

Even in the case of the Stack Exchange log-in/signup (where you provide a password on the site), it goes through the Stack Exchange OpenId provider (which stores them using a salted hash - so the original cannot be recovered easily, if at all).

tl;dr - no one can see your passwords on Stack Overflow. Not moderators, not employees, not even you. Because we don't have passwords.

Comment: So no one can hack me? So what to do if a hacker in stackoverflow found my IP adress?

Comment: @ceko - you worry too much about things that have not happened to you. And what if someone _does_ know your IP? What good is that to them?

Comment: I am also not saying anything about "no one can hack me" - who knows, perhaps someone can. But not through a password on Stack Overflow. Perhaps it could happen through your password on other sites. If you use the same password everywhere, that's your fault.

Comment: No I mean if a moderator is a hacker what can I do they can hack my stackoverflow account

Comment: We hold moderators to a high standard. Again - what do you mean by "hack my stackoverflow account"? They have access to your email address, your IP address and more. If we find that a moderator abused their moderation privileges, they will be removed as moderator.

Comment: Oh I understand thank you. We can report moderators then right? How can I report a moderator?

Comment: Use the [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form (linked in the footer) - that goes directly to Stack Exchange employees and moderators will not see that information.

Comment: @ceko If all of your account passwords are the same, then yes someone can hack you. Stack Overflow moderators are the least of your worries.